# How to optimize norm calculation in Matlab?

Tags: optimization, matlab

I had like to optimize the following Matlab code :

> x = linspace(-5,5,100);
>   y = linspace(-5,5,100);
>   z = linspace(-5,5,100);
>   [xp,yp,zp] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
>
> norm = sqrt(xp.^2+yp.^2+zp.^2);

I improved it a little using realsqrt :

norm_0 = sqrt(xp.^2+yp.^2+zp.^2)       10.106 s   37.0%
norm_1 = realsqrt(xp.^2+yp.^2+zp.^2)   10.100 s   35.0%

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

- `sqrt()` is expensive, so make sure you really need it, or - as Jonas pointed out - if you could instead threshold against the square of the radius
- depending on your data, use the knowledge about the symmetry of the norm to reduce the number of sqrt calculations
- precalculate the squares before generating the meshgrid

something like (untested):

```
x = linspace(-5, 5, 100);
y = linspace(-5, 5, 100);
z = linspace(-5, 5, 100);
[xp2, yp2, zp2] = meshgrid(x(1:end/2).^2, y(1:end/2).^2, z(1:end/2).^2);
norm_quadrant = sqrt(xp2 + yp2 + zp2);
norm_temp1 = cat(1, norm_quadrant, flipdim(norm_quadrant, 1));
norm_temp2 = cat(2, norm_temp1, flipdim(norm_temp1, 2));
norm_complete = cat(3, norm_temp2, flipdim(norm_temp2, 3));
```

Comment: @Jonas: It could work, especially as I am in cylindrical geometry.

Comment: @groovingandi: As soon as I have the time to test this, I will. I will let you know. Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this individual line can be optimized very much. However, for it to take 10 seconds, I guess that it is called inside a loop, which suggests that there is potential for optimizing the entire function.

Also, you may be trying to create a circle somewhere later by thresholding the radius. Instead of taking the square root, you could instead threshold against the square of the radius, and make the code thus faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just use standard norm function, it is probably implemented using C, which makes it faster that doing anything in many steps in Matlab.

Comment: Sorry in this particular case, I don't see how to take element-wise the norm of the vector [xp,yp,zp]. Any idea ?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: `norm` won't work here. If you call it with an array, `norm` returns a matrix norm, not a list of vector norms.

Comment: @Jonas: you can use `norm(X, 2, 'rows')` to tell Matlab to take a vector norm of each row of the matrix X (returning a column vector). Or vice versa if you pass `'cols'` or `'columns'`.